# Differential Hyper-V backups with max file limit

Tags: backup, virtualization, virtual-machines, hyper-v

I am looking for a product that can take incremental or differential backups of running VMs on a hyper-v host and importantly can chunk or span the backups across multiple individual files no larger than a set limit in its backing store / backup directory.  In a very similar manner to how large files were chunked in the floppy disk/fat16/fat32 era.

The reason for this is that our backing store will only accept individual files less than 400Gb and several vhdx's are larger than that.  Loads of products out there but none I can find with this important feature.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can always do what you want with an external utility. We had similar request from the customer years ago and had successfully solved the issue for Veeam who can’t limit backup file sizes itself.

https://forums.veeam.com/veeam-agent-for-windows-f33/any-way-to-limit-vbk-vib-file-size-t32186.html

Other backup software like say Acronis and CommVault aren’t different.

Comment: thanks, really helpful, the only disadvantage is that you either need to stage the files or have control of the copy process.  Certainly a decent solution if you are using veeam,

Comment: Yes, you’re absolutely correct about the drawbacks! Features come up with a price.